# Postgres: how do you optimize queries on date column with low selectivity?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 143 million rows (and growing), its current size is 107GB. One of the columns in the table is of type date and it has low selectivity. For any given date, its reasonable to assume that there are somewhere between 0.5 to 4 million records with the same date value.

Now, if someone tries to do something like this:

```
select * from large_table where date_column > '2020-01-01' limit 100
```

It will execute "forever", and if you EXPLAIN ANALYZE it, you can see that its doing a table scan. So the first (and only so far) idea is to try and make this into an index scan. If Postgres can scan a subsection of an index and return the "limit" number of records, it sounds fast to me:

```
create index our_index_on_the_date_column ON large_table (date_column DESC);

VACUUM ANALYZE large_table;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from large_table where date_column > '2020-01-01' limit 100;

                                                                 QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..37.88 rows=100 width=893) (actual time=0.034..13.520 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on large_table  (cost=0.00..13649986.80 rows=36034774 width=893) (actual time=0.033..13.506 rows=100 loops=1)
         Filter: (date_column > '2020-01-01'::date)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 7542
 Planning Time: 0.168 ms
 Execution Time: 18.412 ms
(6 rows)
```

It still reverts to a sequential scan. Please disregard the execution time as this took 11 minutes before caching came into action. We can force it to use the index, by reducing the number of returned columns to what's being covered by the index:

```
select date_column from large_table where date_column > '2019-01-15' limit 100
                                                                                    QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..3.42 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.051..0.064 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using our_index_on_the_date_column on large_table  (cost=0.57..907355.11 rows=31874888 width=4) (actual time=0.050..0.056 rows=100 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (date_column > '2019-01-15'::date)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.082 ms
 Execution Time: 0.083 ms
(6 rows)
```

But this is of course a contrived example, since the table is very wide and covering all parts of the table in the index is not feasible.

So, anyone who can share some guidance on how to get some performance when using columns with low selectivity as predicates?

Comment: The first plan shows that the row estimates are way off. Postgres thinks the Seq Scan will return 36034774 rows,  but in reality it was only 100 out of 7642 - so that table if far from being "large".  Does `analyze large_table` change the first query plan?

Comment: An ORDER BY might help, but you have to get the stats correct as well.

Comment: Isn't "VACUUM ANALYZE large_table;" after creating the index going to do the trick? (update the stats)

Comment: And yes "order by desc" (which was in the same order as the index), makes the execution plan use the index in all my examples.